# open folder, manipulate files in excel, save excel files in new directory

Tags: vba

I have a folder called "maildir".  It contains folders named numerically.  These folders contain text files.

I have hacked together a macro that opens the numerically named folder, opens its first text file, and copies the contents into Excel.  It then opens the next file in the directory, and copies the new file into a new sheet in the same workbook.

Then, the procedure deletes all the rows below row five, for every sheet in the workbook.

The next step combines the content from all the sheets into a new sheet called "Combined".

Then, all sheets but "Combined" are deleted

The next step saves the workbook into a new folder called "enron_excel".

This is where I am stuck: I was able to get the macro to work fine until I added a "For Loop" which is designed to both open the numerically named folders, and save them with numerical names in the "enron_excel" folder.

But when I run the code, and look in the "enron_excel" folder, it seems that the "combined" step has been missed.  Does anyone know what happened?

Thank you.

```
Sub all()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim J As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wks As Worksheet

For i = 1 To 3 ' What I want this for loop to do: open the file called "1" (and later 2 and 3), manipulate the data then save with the same number in a different file


Path = "C:\Users\Kate\Desktop\enron4\maildir\" ' open folder in a directory
Filename = Dir(Path & i & "*.txt") ' opens a folder, and a text file in that folder
Do While Filename <> "" ' opens file in folder and copies to sheet in excel workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
    Loop


    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' deletes all the rows below row five
    ws.Range("5:1000").Delete
    Next ws

On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select ' combines all the sheets into one worksheet
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(J).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next J



    Sheets("Combined").Select '  selects the sheet calls "Combined" and deletes all the others
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        If wks.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then wks.Delete
    Next wks


Path = "C:\Users\Kate\Desktop\enron_excel\" ' this opens a new path
FolderName = i
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FolderName ' this saves the file in the new path with the new name
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use *File System Object*.
Something like:

```
Sub ReadAllfiles()
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim sFile As Scripting.File
    Dim subFldr As Scripting.Folder
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim fldrPath As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim fldrDesc As String
    Dim wbTxt As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wbDesc As Workbook
    fldrDesc = "C:\User\Yourdestination\" '<~~ change to suit
    fldrPath = "C:\User\Yourfolder" '<~~ change to suit
    'iterate each folder of your source folder
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    For Each subFldr In fso.GetFolder(fldrpath).SubFolders
        wbName = subFldr.Name
        Set wbDesc = Workbooks.Add 'add a new workbook
        'create the combined sheet
        Set ws = wbDesc.Sheets(1): ws.Name = "Combined"
        'iterate each file on the folder
        For Each sFile In subFldr.Files
            fname = sFile.ParentFolder.Path & "\" & sFile.Name
            Set wbTxt = Workbooks.Open(fname)
            'I'm not sure why a text file will yield to multiple sheet
            'so if that is really the case use your loop
            'copy the 1st 4 rows to Combined sheet
            wbTxt.Sheets(1).Range("1:4").Copy _
                ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wbTxt.Close False 'close source text file
        Next
        wbDesc.SaveAs fldrDesc & wbName 'save the workbook
        wbDesc.Close True 'close
    Next
End Sub
```

I just based it on how you describe what you want. Not tested though.
You will need to add reference to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime.* HTH.

Comment: I'm getting the error "object variable or with block variable not set".  I added the reference to microsoft scripting Runtime.

Comment: @user3411757 Which line is highlighted when you debug?

Comment: @user3411757 I was not able to set `fso` that's why it errors out. I added it so please try it out :) Also I've tried and tested it and it works.